# Passing values from custom angular directive to other page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-controller

I've a custom directive that has values stored in an object i want these values from custom directive input and dropdown to be passed as an object to the page where i am referring this directive. this directive values will be passed to the main page when i click apply button which is on my main page, i've tried following but can't get the values from the custom directive in my page where i use this directive. Please suggest how can i pass values from directive to a different page. I need the values from query object in request variable i've declared in a function in my main page controller defined at the last

**The custom directive template file metrics-dashboard-configuration.html**

```
<div>
    <span>Service Level (SL)</span>
    <select ng-model="selection.serviceLevelOption" ng-options="serviceLevelObject.value as serviceLevelObject.text for serviceLevelObject in selection.serviceLevels.values" ng-init="selection.serviceLevelOption='30'"></select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selection.inputText" />
</div>
```

**Custom directive declaration and controller**

```
function metricsDashboardConfiguration() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      query: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'metrics-dashboard-configuration.html',
    controller: metricsDashboardConfigurationCtrl
  };
}

function metricsDashboardConfigurationCtrl($scope) {
$scope.query = {};    
$scope.selection = {
    serviceLevels: {
             values: [
               {value : "15" , text : "15"},
               {value : "30" , text : "30"},
               {value : "45" , text : "45"},
               {value : "60" , text : "60"},
               {value : "120" , text : "120"}
             ]
        },           
    inputText: "test"
};

$scope.updateRequest = function() {
   $scope.query.inputText = $scope.selection.inputText;
   $scope.query.serviceLevels= $scope.selection.serviceLevels;
};

$scope.$watch('selection.inputText', $scope.updateRequest, true);
$scope.$watch('selection.serviceLevels', $scope.updateRequest, true);
```

**The html page where i'm using the directive**

```
<metrics-dashboard-configuration query="queryData" update-Queues-Dashboard="updateQueuesDashboard()"></metrics-dashboard-configuration>
```

**The controller of the page where i need values of the custom directive**

```
$scope.queryData = {
  inputText : "",
  trailingWindows: []
};
$scope.updateQueuesDashboard = function () {     
  var request = angular.copy($scope.queryData);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The model you have used in your `metrics-dashboard-configuration.html` file is `ng-model="selection.serviceLevelOption"` and `ng-model="selection.myInput"`, but in your directive you are watching `selection.inputText` and `selection.trailingWindows`

Check this working [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1vn07j1Ozi1U27qJOf5i?p=preview) and verify what is going wrong in your code.

Comment: check your watchers `$scope.$watch('selection.inputText', $scope.updateRequest, true);
$scope.$watch('selection.trailingWindows', $scope.updateRequest, true);`

Comment: this is not the issue it was just a typo, the issue is not able to pass values from directive to other pages where i've used the custom directive

Comment: Check this working plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1vn07j1Ozi1U27qJOf5i?p=preview and verify what is going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the model bound to the UI elements of the directive in the view where it is being used then, you should make property in isolated scope same way as you have done by passing `query` in isolated scope.

Something like this:

```
function metricsDashboardConfiguration() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      query: '=',
      serviceLevelOption: '=',
      inputText: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'metrics-dashboard-configuration.html',
    controller: metricsDashboardConfigurationCtrl
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<metrics-dashboard-configuration service-level-option="option" input-text="inText" query="queryData" update-Queues-Dashboard="updateQueuesDashboard()"></metrics-dashboard-configuration>
```

and then what ever value is being updated from the ui or directive controller it will be reflected in the `option` and `inText` variables.

Comment: I've for the same reason created a query variable which has all the data but my problem is not able to get values from this query object in my page where i am using this directive